# Setting controller dynamically Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing, angular-controller

I have a query related to setting controllers at runtime. 
I want something like:

```
.state{'app.thisState',
   url: '/thisUrl',
   views:{
     templateUrl: 'templates/some_template.html',
     controller: 'XYZCtrlr' //This is where I want to set different controllers depending on the scenario.
   }};
```

How can we set controllers at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [**`controllerProvider`**](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#controllers) option of ui-router state

```
.state ('app.thisState', { //<-- correct syntax here
    url: '/thisUrl',
    views: {
        templateUrl: 'templates/some_template.html',
        controller: 'XYZCtrlr',
        controllerProvider: function($stateParams) { //<-- add dependencies here
            //perform logic here
            var ctrlName = $stateParams.type + "Controller";
            return ctrlName; //return string name here, which will the name of controller.
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you please `elaborate var ctrlName = $stateParams.type + "Controller";`. What is happening in this line? Sorry I'm a newbie in angular

Comment: Basically just for demonstration, I did inject a $stateParams dependency & then I'm reading state parameter & creating controller name.. **I wrote that code just for demo, with comments**

Comment: I get it. Is it possible to have $rootScope dependency here?